# Detect rules applied to messages in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

Is it possible to detect rules applied to messages in c#? I have search for it and found these links dealing with rules:

[Managing Rules in the Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206763.aspx)

[Specifying Rule Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206766.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ***No***. Outlook does not store this particular information anywhere, so you cannot detect what rules have been applied in the past.

Furthermore, the application of rules doesn't trigger rule-specific events, so you cannot be notified either.

You might be able to *predict* what rules will apply to a particular message while it is being received, but that is a different question than what you are asking.

Perhaps if you explained what you need this for exactly, we might be able to help you with a different kind of solution.